# ajax post (no Json) taking too much

Tags: jquery, performance, time

I have the following issue and hope someone can tell me where's the problem..

My form has 3 select option for state, city and neighborhood. The last 2 selects depends of it's previous one value.
Everything works quite well, but takes 2 seconds to show the new options (after change in the previous select)..
I understand json is not needed around here (right?).. but is there a way to decrease the response time?

```
function carga(tipo, valor, selector){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "include/sel.php",
        data: { tipo: tipo, valor: valor },
        error: function() {
            $(selector).html('<option>Ha ocurrido un error</option>');
      },
        success: function (response) {
            $(selector).html(response);
        }
    })
```

}

EDIT: I forgot.. i'm using xampp

here is my sel.php

```
include('dbcs.php');

$i = $_POST['tipo'];
$valor = $_POST['valor'];

switch($i){
case 'provincia':
    $consulta_sql = 'Select * from tbl_zona_provincias';
    break;
case 'partido':
    $consulta_sql = 'Select idPartido, partido from tbl_zona_partidos Where codProvincia = "'.$_POST['valor'].'"';
    break;
case 'localidad':
    $consulta_sql = 'Select idLocalidad, localidad from tbl_zona_localidades Where idPartido = "'.$_POST['valor'].'"';
    break;
}


if(!$resultados = $db->query($consulta_sql)){
die('Se produjo un error al intentar enviar la consulta [' . $db->error . ']');
} else {

while($row = $resultados->fetch_array()){
    if($i == 'provincia'){
        $option = '<option value="'.$row['codProvincia'].'">'.$row['provincia'].'</option>';
    } else if($i == 'partido'){
        $option = '<option value="'.$row['idPartido'].'">'.$row['partido'].'</option>';
    } else {
        $option = '<option value="'.$row['idLocalidad'].'">'.$row['localidad'].'</option>';
    }
    echo $option;   
}
$resultados->free();
}
$db->close();
```

Comment: i don't think it is a problem with the javascript, you need check your server side code and network latency

Comment: it may depends on your net speed, or page load time of sel.php. if your options arent a lot you can save them in javascript arrays , or if they are lots of options , save most used items in js arrays , when users select an option , you can show it a loading image !
this doesnot solve your question , its just a suggested trick ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you store all states, cities and neightborhoods at the beginning, in a multidimensional array, you will decrease the treatment time.
The array could be in this structure :

**IN PHP**

```
$selectOptions = array(
     state_id => array(
          country_id =>array(
               'name'=>country_name,
               'content'=>array(
                      neightborhood_id => neightborhood_name,
                 ),
             ),
           country_id...
        )
    ),
     state_id...
);
```

And in your page

```
<script ...>
    var selectOptions = <?php echo json_encode($selectOptions)?>;
</script>
```

Then, for the **state** list, do

```
$('#stateselector').on('change', function() {
    $('#countrySelector').empty();
    $(selectOptions[$(this).val()]).each(function(id, value) {
      $('#countrySelector').append($('<option />').attr('value', id).text(value.name));
    }
}
```

And for the **country** list, do

```
$('#countryselector').on('change', function() {
    $('#neightborhoodSelector').empty();
    $(selectOptions[$(stateselector).val()][$(this).val()]).each(function(id, value) {
      $('#neightborhoodSelector').append($('<option />').attr('value', id).text(value));
    }
}
```

Comment: the thing is I will end up with a huge array since this are all the states, cities and neighborhood of an entire country.. right?

Comment: Or you can load all states and countries, and keep Ajax loading for neightborhoods... A good compromise!